# jQuery iterative validation of radio button groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have several radio button controls on my form.

```
<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="M">Male
<input type="radio" name="Gender" value="F">Female

<input type="radio" name="Vehicle" value="H">Honda
<input type="radio" name="Vehicle" value="T">Toyota
<input type="radio" name="Vehicle" value="L">Lexus
<input type="radio" name="Vehicle" value="M">Mercedes
<input type="radio" name="Vehicle" value="V">VW

<input type="radio" name="Device" value="D">Desktop
<input type="radio" name="Device" value="L">Laptop
<input type="radio" name="Device" value="S">SmartPhone
<input type="radio" name="Device" value="T">Tablet

<input type="button" onclick="javascript:ButtonClick();" name="Next">
```

Now I want that when `ButtonClick()` is called, it should validate that at least one radio button from *each* group is called.

What I am thinking to have is a jQuery function which will loop through all radio button controls and validate them by each group.

```
$("<CORRECT SELECTOR>").each(function() {
    // Validate this radio button group
});
```

Please point me if this is already asked. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: 1. Determine groups. 2. Validate each group. 3. Remove post :P

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

[SEE jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SRVa7/9/)

```
function ButtonClick() {
    var valid = true;
    var grps = $.unique($('input[type=radio]').map(function () {
        return this.name
    }).get());
    $.each(grps, function (_, grp) {
        if (!$('input[type=radio]').filter('[name="' + grp + '"]').is(':checked')) {
            alert('No radio ' + grp + ' is checked!'); 
            valid = false;
            return;
        }
    });    

    if(valid) alert('At least one radio of each group checked!');
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, once again. +1

Comment: @EricG i don't see anything wrong in your codepen and it is readable

Comment: Was merely wondering what you thought about longer but potentially more efficient script?

Comment: The most important part is readability imho. Here performance shouldn't really matter, i don't think OP will get to check for thousand checkboxes at once.

Answer (score 1):

It's longer but.. efficient, readable & reusable.

[Demo @ CodePen.io (better than JSFiddle :cool:)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGHjy)

```
function verify() {
  var groups = determineGroups();
  var invalidGroups = verifyGroups( groups );

  if( invalidGroups && invalidGroups.length ) {
    var groupsString = invalidGroups.join("," );

    notify( "Please specify values for " + groupsString );
  }
}

function determineGroups() {
  var groupsHash = {}, 
      groups = [];

  $("input[type='radio']").each(function(){

    var groupName = this.name;
    if( !groupsHash[groupName] ) {

      groupsHash[ groupName ] = 1;

      groups.push( groupName );
    }
  });
  return groups;
}

function verifyGroups( groups ) {

  var invalidGroups = [];

  for( var i = 0, ln = groups.length; i < ln; i++ ) {

    if( !groupHasValue( groups[ i ] ) ) {

      invalidGroups.push( groups[ i ] );
    }
  }
  return invalidGroups;
}

function groupHasValue( group ) {

  var hasValidValue = false;

  $("input[name=" + group + "]").each(function() {

    if( this.checked ) {
      hasValidValue = true;
    }
  });

  return hasValidValue;
}

function notify( txt ) {
  alert( txt );
}
```

Comment: +1 for reusability but i disagree regarding codepen more cool than jsfiddle ;)

Comment: Thank you! :) Whats so nice about jsfiddle? Its so slow for me, and you need to re-run. Maybe I should get used to a shortcut for that..? Hope its legal to ask in the comments this Q.

Comment: I like to have to rerun script once i need it. I hate when typing code to get warnings/errors which i don't care of while coding. But that's just my opinion of course

Comment: Makes sense, I have to agree. I try to type fast enough + syntaxerror-free asap, later fill in my method contents :P

Answer (score 0):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C4wWw/19/)***

```
$('[name="Next"]').click(function () {
    var radios = [];
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function () {
        radios.push(this.name);
    });
    radios = Getunique(radios);
    console.log(radios);
    $.each(radios, function (i, val) {
        var selected = $('[name=' + val + ']').is(':checked');
        if (!selected) {
            alert("select " + val);
        }
    });
});

function Getunique(list) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(list, function (i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
    });
    return result;
}
```